# Plotting Stata charts from a table output over time and category

Tags: charts, time-series, stata, linechart, summary

I am using the following command to display summary stats and compare the distributions of various different regions:

```
version 16: table Year if region == 1, c( p25 sales p50 sales p75 sales mean sales)
```

Right now, to create a chart that displays the comparison between the two regions I am generating variables 4 variables for each of the regions

```
levelsof region, local(levels)

foreach l of local levels {
    
    gen reg_`l'_p25 = .
    gen reg_`l'_p50 = .
    gen reg_`l'_p75 = .
    gen reg_`l'_mean = .
forval i = 2000/2010{
    sum sales if region == `l' & Year == `i', d
    replace reg_`l'_p25 =  r(p25) if region == `l' &  Year == `i'
    replace reg_`l'_p50 =   r(p50) if region == `l' &  Year == `i'
    replace reg_`l'_p75 =  r(p75) if region == `l' &  Year == `i'
    replace reg_`l'_mean =  r(mean) if region == `l' &  Year == `i'
}
```

}

then I plot using:

```
twoway(mband reg_1_p25 ... ) (mband reg_2_p25.... ) (band reg_3_p25... )
```

Is there a better way? quicker? easier? to generate such stats and then plot them in stata?

Many thanks!

sampak

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
collapse (mean) mean=sales (p25) p25=sales (p50) p50=sales (p75) p75=sales, by(region year)
```

to get a reduced dataset including your summary statistics.

See also the help for `graph bar`, `graph hbar`, `graph dot`. Each of those commandswill plot all those summary statistics for you. The first approach doesn't rule out the second, but it's more flexible, especially if you want say line charts for different years.

Comment: that is a lot quicker, thanks!